# TYPO3 Oops, an error occurred! Code: 202402180809040864ba5c

Tags: database, typo3, typoscript

I have an error in TYPO3 when i try to show data on my Page.
I Try to connect to my DDEV db.

In my additional.php:

```
'DB' => [
  'Connections' => [
    'Default' => [
      'dbname' => 'db',
      'driver' => 'mysqli',
      'host' => 'db',
      'password' => 'db',
      'port' => '3306',
      'user' => 'db',
    ],
  ],
],
```

I dont think that this is the error.

I created in the database a table called `gamesrate`.

Now i try to import it in my TypoScript:

```
lib.myCustomQuery = CONTENT
lib.myCustomQuery {
  table = gamerate
  select {
    pidInList = this
    orderBy = uid DESC
    # where = uid=1 # Falls du eine WHERE-Bedingung hinzufügen möchtest
    max = 1 # Begrenzt die Anzahl der zurückgegebenen Datensätze
  }
  
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
      field = title
      wrap = <h2>|</h2>
    }
    
    20 = TEXT
    20 {
      field = description
      wrap = <p>|</p>
    }
  }
}
page.30 < lib.myCustomQuery
```

On my page show Following:

```
Oops, an error occurred! Code: 202402180809040864ba5c
```

I did try to create a separate database but that didn't work either.

Comment: I could fix that error but now just nothing render, my Column names are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you created a table "gamesrate" but in your TS you reference "gamerate" instead.

You should enable the debug mode preset in the Install Tool configuration. That will give you a more detailed error message, that will allow us to help you more specifically.

(You can also check out the exact error in either your sys_log table (that you can inspect via the Log backend module), or in the logfile saved in var/log/ .)

Comment: @bwfront Futhermore there exists a bug in TYPO3 that prevents that some TypoScript like yours is rendered: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/100849

Answer (score 0):

in addition.php it must be:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB'] = [
    'Connections' => [
        'Default' => [
            'dbname' => 'db',
            'driver' => 'mysqli',
            'host' => 'db',
            'password' => 'db',
            'port' => '3306',
            'user' => 'db',
        ],
    ],
];
```